# Custom validation constraint

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-annotations

```
    public class Person {
    List <Address> addresssList;

    @Notnull
    String salary;

    @dateformat
    String dob
    }




 @ValidAddress

    public class Address {

    String streetname;
    String appartmentnumber;

    }
```

I created custom annotation to invoke the constraint if street name or apartment number is empty. As the class person holds address. When i try to execute the below snippet. It shows only the constraint violation in person class not in address class.

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(personObject);
```

How to raise constraints through custom class if set the address object in person class.

Answer (score 0):

@Valid annotation instructs the Spring to validate the referenced objects.